# python os popup function limitation win 95/98

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have small python game written in pygame, I used py2exe to get executable app, and when I sent it to a 3rd person, this erorr pop up to him:

[image]

I'm using pygame, tkinter, time, sys, random modules in my app.

Don't have idea why he got this problem, and I really need to make this work.

I'm using windows 10 and working, on windows 7 tested too.